# Does gcc search for subdirecties in LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \ in MakeFile

Tags: gcc

In Makefile,

If I have

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \
        ${TOP}/directory1 \
```

Is compiler smart enough to search .h files in *sub*-directories of 'directory1'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, the compiler only searches in the directories listed with `-I`.

If your makefile is smart enough to expand LOCAL_C_INCLUDES to include sub directories then that's different, but that's not gcc's doing.

If you have an include like `"subdir/header.h"` then the compiler will find the header in the sub-directory, of course, but that's not really a 'search'.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a question of smart or not.
Suppose a user add the `/` directory. You don't want the compiler to take hours.

What you  have to do if you have a subdirectory is to add the subdir in the define statement:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
```